# Why is my rails app reloading application.html.erb every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app serving up static content (for now).

Every time I change view it reloads the application.html.erb content which makes the header and footer flicker and look ugly.

I have another rails app that doesn't do this. I am not clear on how the mechanism works, assumably with some sort of ajax call for the individual view content.

My route.rb is as follows

```
Zode64::Application.routes.draw do

  get "contact/index"
  get "about/index"
  get "home/index"

  root :to => 'home#index'

  match "home" => "home#index"
  match "about" => "about#index"
  match "contact" => "contact#index"
end
```

And my link is like this

```
<li><%= link_to "home", "home" %></li>
```

The app I am having trouble with is here http://www.zode64.com the app where I see the application.html.erb not loading is here http://whatsthebeef.org/blog.

What do I need to do to prevent this flicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's just you. The flicker is either the way your browser is rendering the page, your internet connection, or the application/server's response time. (Given that you notice a difference between the two, it's probably not the first.)

There is no AJAX page loading on either site, they both completely render and send the page to the browser for each request.

For example, I see little to no flicker on *both* sites.

Answer (score 1):

Its also a question of cache. If your images and webpages are cached, you don't need to reload the entire page from the server but from your hard drive. The flicker really comes from that difference in loading time.

A terrible alternative would be to use frames for your layout structure.

However using Ajax can be a viable solution so long as you trust that visitors have Javascript active.